# c++ preprocessor or template to switch types

Tags: c++

I noticed that the python library [scipy](https://github.com/stefanv/scipy3) has a test for [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org) (in `fftw_dct.c`) that uses a clever preprocessor macro to swap between float and double precision.

```
#ifdef DCT_TEST_USE_SINGLE
typedef float float_prec;
#define PF "%.7f"
#define FFTW_PLAN fftwf_plan
#define FFTW_MALLOC fftwf_malloc
#define FFTW_FREE fftwf_free
#define FFTW_PLAN_CREATE fftwf_plan_r2r_1d
#define FFTW_EXECUTE fftwf_execute
#define FFTW_DESTROY_PLAN fftwf_destroy_plan
#define FFTW_CLEANUP fftwf_cleanup
#else
typedef double float_prec;
#define PF "%.18f"
#define FFTW_PLAN fftw_plan
#define FFTW_MALLOC fftw_malloc
#define FFTW_FREE fftw_free
#define FFTW_PLAN_CREATE fftw_plan_r2r_1d
#define FFTW_EXECUTE fftw_execute
#define FFTW_DESTROY_PLAN fftw_destroy_plan
#define FFTW_CLEANUP fftw_cleanup
#endif
```

I know that macros are **EVIL**, but this seems like a reasonably transparent manner of utilizing a library that allows a single or double precision approach to solving your problem. We created a Template wrapper approach that mimics this swapping between **float** and **double**, but it seems an overly complicated approach especially when considering readability.

Assuming that both the **float** and **double** variants of a class don't need to be available in an executable, is there any other approach that might be better at adhering to good C++ design principles that isn't overly complicated?  I'd prefer an answer that applies to C++03, since we need to integrate a design that works with legacy code.

Comment: Create wrapper functions and stuff them in a namespace.

Comment: You don't need functions with different names in C++, you can just overload for `float` and `double`.

Comment: Can you explain, what is so complicated about your template solution?

Comment: Em, did you notice that the cited code is c-compiled ? There are no templates in C and the macros are probably the only way to go.

Comment: So? I've wrapped everything right down to Christmas presents. C functions are easy. Less tape and you don't have to look for the scissors.